# golang hex encode to upper case string?

Tags: go, encoding, hex

What is the best way in *go* to encode like:
hex.EncodeToString

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#EncodeToString

But into **upper case** letters?

Comment: First encode, then use [`strings.ToUpper`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToUpper).

Comment: This works, but here the system must go through the bytes 2 times. It would be nice to get it in one run.

Comment: The only option then is to write your own encoder. The source for `Encode` is pretty simple, so I don't see a reason why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may call [`strings.ToUpper()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToUpper) on the result:

```
src := []byte("Hello")

s := hex.EncodeToString(src)
fmt.Println(s)

s = strings.ToUpper(s)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Or you may use [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) with `%X` verb:

```
s = fmt.Sprintf("%X", src)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Output of the above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zhskZ9GZsZ1)):

```
48656c6c6f
48656C6C6F
48656C6C6F
```

If performance matters, implement your own encoder. Look at the source of `encoding/hex`. It's really simple:

```
const hextable = "0123456789abcdef"

func EncodeToString(src []byte) string {
    dst := make([]byte, EncodedLen(len(src)))
    Encode(dst, src)
    return string(dst)
}

func Encode(dst, src []byte) int {
    j := 0
    for _, v := range src {
        dst[j] = hextable[v>>4]
        dst[j+1] = hextable[v&0x0f]
        j += 2
    }
    return len(src) * 2
}
```

Yes, all you need is to change `hextable` to contain the uppercased letters.